# Display only the image and make the rest of the pages faded using css in ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I am displaying an image when a button is clicked. How can I set my CSS for the Image to make the image center of the page and rest of the page faded and not clickable. I want to display only the image and the rest of the pages should be faded. how can I do this with CSS

```
 <img runat="server" id="aajaxLoader" style="background-color: White; z-index:auto;  width: 200px;"
                                        src="styles/images/UploadImage1.gif"  />
```

Comment: What you're looking for is called [Lightbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightbox_(JavaScript)) and has great many implementations. It's not related in any way to ASP.NET please tag the question properly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look to javascript not ASP.Net check this [Lightbox2](http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/), I think this will do the job